# Select only parent element of unordered list minus the sub list using css selectors?

Tags: html, css

Just trying to style the first ul li a only without styling the sub ul li a.  I realize there is no such thing as parent selectors in CSS and proably for good reasons, so how would I accomplish this without assigning all of the li's a class?  Maybe this is impossible, which is why I am asking. Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <h2>Headline 2</h2>

    <div>
        <p>Some Paragraph 1</p>
        <ul class="list">
            <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 1 (=)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 2 (=)</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 2a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 2b</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">List 1 Item 3 (=)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p>Some paragraph 2</p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">List 2 Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what I would like to target
[image]

Again, I realize I could just add classes to all of them and get the result I want, I just want to know if there is another way.

Using css selectors, here is how I could target the sublist (not what I want)

```
ul.list li > ul li a{
   ...
}
```

Targeting the first ul plus the sublist (not what I want)

```
ul.list > li a{
   ...
}
```

[image]

Here is a fiddle for you convience.
http://jsfiddle.net/94e2fo30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the first list and its sublist is that the first is preceded by a `p`.

```
p + ul > li > a {
    color: red;
}
```

will give:

[image]

Comment: Appreciate that, however if the paragraph was inside the div would this still be possible using a different syntax obviously, again thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? The first `p` is inside the `div`

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.  I was refering to the second paragraph.  So I would just go off what you said and write this way p + ul.list > li > a

Thanks again, I'm trying to understand CSS selectors better.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myDiv > div > ul > li > a{color:red}
```

since both your parent li's are direct children of ul's which are direct children of divs which are children of #myDiv

This will work in your case, but I wouldn't recommend doing it. Anytime css starts too look like this you'll want to rethink your organization